# React - form for edit entity from BD

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I want to make a form for creating and editing an entity from the database.
And now I’m thinking about how best to do it.

**1.** I want filling out a form and SUBMIT it - than an entity is created in the database.
**2.** I also need to be able to EDIT an entity from the database in order to use the same components, but for editing. I receive data from the database, and with this data I initialize the form components.

**Questions:**
**1)** Tell me where to read about how  to do this in best?
I'm using: **react-hook-form**

**2)** Do I think correctly that I need to use CONTROLLED components so that when editing an entity, I can fill the form components with the current data of the entity from the DataBase.

**3**) If you I a state, then maybe I can do it without react-hook-form ?

How to do it in best, could you show me an example...

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.